# ASP.NET Role Authentication Breaks With Session

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, cookies, .aspxauth

Working on an internal portal, we needed certain things about a user stored so we created our own WebUser/WebUserStore but I've hit a weird issue and I was hoping someone would have run into this before.

Being ASP it's a lot of code strewn throughout, so I won't bother pasting it all here. But here is the issue:

- Any number of users can login to the home screen.
- If any user navigates to a page that makes any session call (either
  setting or Session.Remove()) then no more users can log in, the login
  page just flashes and you're back at the login screen.
- Any user that was logged in while the one user trigger the session will still be able to log out and in and out and in, as long as they still have the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.
- If you delete the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie then that user will get stuck on the login screen as well.

Hacky fixes that may help pinpoint the problem (each of these stops the issue):

- Recycling the application pool in IIS resets it so everyone can log in again.**
- Setting the following (but you get the nasty url):

`<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri" />`

- Add this right before calling the IdentityHelper.SignIn(...).

  Session["ANYKEY!"] = false;
- Just adding this empty event to the global.asax.cs

  ```
  void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  }
  ```

This is also on a per-browser basis. So on one machine with 3 different browsers you can replicate the issue using only 1 user. Once you trigger a session call in one browser, the other browsers if they weren't logged in (and had the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie) are now locked out.

Stepping through the login process wasn't revealing anything, everything is normal and fires all the way through authenticationManager.SignIn(...) any seems fine but is mystically not actually authenticated and returned to the login screen?

Can anyone think of what's wrong so that as soon as I touch session all users can't login, and only the ones who already have their session cookie can continue logging in and out?